# SrpUxSnapIn.dll Error when trying to Add New AppLocker rule for specific user

Tags: windows-10, dll, applocker

I'm setting up a reference machine and want to disable access to the Windows Store App for a specific user through the Local Security Policy application. This is one of the last things I need to complete before I am ready to capture and deploy my image. I've learned that Windows 10 Pro no longer has the ability to block access to the Store App through Group Policy, so I decided to make a rule using App Locker. Unfortunately, whenever I try add a rule, I receive a SrpUxSnapIn.dll error. Here's a couple of screenshots that show the error in it entirety:

[image: SrpUxSnapIn.dll - MMC has detected an error...]

[image: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException]

This error occurs immediately after **clicking the select button** when attempting to browse for the Store app via the *Use an installed packaged app as a reference option.*

I have tried running sfc /scannow and the dism /restorehealth cmdlet, but it didn't find any errors. I also did some reading on Google and saw that some people recommended having legacy versions of the .Net Framework installed, but all those articles are Windows 7 related. I did go ahead and add .Net legacy support through the Add/Remove Windows features app. Doesn't seem to resolve my issue.

I did run across this TechNet forum discussion (see link in comment), but a clean install really isn't an option for me since I don't want to have to completely redo my reference machine. Also, it appears that the issue might just come back based on the TechNet forum discussion.

Does anyone know what I can do to resolve this issue?

Comment: [TechNet Forum Discussion](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dda9a993-1e41-41a5-8e0b-918453db3f91/applocker-policy?forum=win10itprogeneral)

Comment: [Disable Store Apps Windows 10 Version 1607 via GPO](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/33ab63b3-955f-4482-9e2d-96fd750f0110/disable-store-apps-windows-10-version-1607-via-gpo?forum=win10itprogeneral)

Comment: [Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520)

Comment: I suggest just removing the Windows Store package itself for the user.

Comment: I will give that a shot. In the past (as in earlier this week), I've had trouble removing packages from a user via powershell. For some reason, once I create a user it seems it won't remove any packages. If I run a script before creating any other users beside my admin account to remove certain provisioned apps and then create my users, it works. Weird.

Comment: @Ramhound Should I download RSAT? Is that why you provided that link?

Comment: The link you provided indicate it's required...But it's easy to download a RSAT for 1511 but then forget to update the tool so it supports 1607.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but for the benefit of people finding this via Google: I was also getting behavior in the GPMC/GPEDIT/AppLocker MMC snap-in.  In my case, it turns out to be that I was running unprivileged and unelevated.  I had permission to modify the GPO in Active Directory, but I did not have admin on the local machine.  Apparently the AppLocker management UI needs admin rights on the local machine to generate the list of applications.  Presumably, Microsoft's AppLocker mgmt code just assumes this, does not check for it, and then crashes.

Hope this helps someone.